# Add a total at the bottom

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add a *Total* at the bottom of my table. Is this possible in my scenario?

```
select country, count(*) from customer
group by country

Country         Count
  USA              5  
  UK              10
 Canada           15 
 Russia           25
                  55  (Requested from SO community)
```

Comment: is it possible for the table rows to grow larger?? or they will remain the same?

Comment: Remain the same @ Hawraa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rollup()`

```
select country, count(*) 
from customer
group by rollup (country )
```

If you want the label "Total" as well, you can use the `grouping` function:

```
select case 
          when grouping(country) = 1 then 'Total' 
          else country 
       end as country, 
       count(*) 
from customer
group by rollup (country )
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/PKFE63954

Answer (score 2):

You can artificially generate a row by using something like

```
select country
    ,count(*) 
from customer
group by country

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total'
    ,COUNT(*)
FROM customer
```

Although this will affect any future calculations you make on this result set as it is a new row in the data.

Comment: Also you could add another column to the row named Total.
    DECLARE @Total int = 0;
    SET atTotal = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer 
    SELECT country, COUNT(*), atTotal
    FROM customer
    GROUP BY country

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
SELECT country
    , count(´1)
FROM customer
GROUP BY country

UNION

SELECT 'TOTAL'
    , count(1)
FROM customer;
```

Comment: Thanks Moe, although it returns the total for the aggregate function it places the Total before Russia not at the bottom. Do you have any insights on why this might be?

Comment: You can add a reverse Identity (ID) to the first Select statement, then in the second Select statement set the ID = 0, and finally to the Union statement, add an Order By clause on ID.

Comment: yes you are right @JasonSmith ,  just change "union" to "union all"

Answer (score -1):

You could add another column to the row named Total

```
        DECLARE @Total int = 0;
        SET @Total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer);

        SELECT country, COUNT(*), [Total] = @Total
        FROM customer
        GROUP BY country
```

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres (and invalid standard SQL)

Comment: Still invalid. `[]` or `@` is invalid in an identifier in SQL. `DECLARE` is invalid in SQL and you can't assign a variable with `total = ` inside a select list.